# Why do I get duplicate tuples in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, duplicates

I am building a library database.

I want to write a query that returns the available books on the library(their isbns,titles,author names,pubname,categoryName and the Number of copies available.

My query involves the following relations (with bold are the primary keys) :

**Book  (ISBN**, title,pubYear,numpages, pubName **)** pubName FK to publisher

**copies  (ISBN, copyNr**, shelf **)** ISBN FK to Book

**borrows (memberID, ISBN, copyNr, date_of_borrowing**, date_of_return **)** memberID FK to member, ISBN FK to Books, (ISBN, copyNr) FK to copies

**belongs_to  (ISBN, categoryName )** SBN FK to Book, categoryName FK to category

**written_by  (ISBN, authID )** ISBN FK to Book, authID FK to author

**author  (authID**, AFirst, ALast, Abirthdate **)**

My approach is the following:

```
SELECT b.isbn, b.title,a.ALast, a.ALast, b.pubName, be.categoryName , COUNT(b.isbn) as Number_of_copies_available
FROM copies as c 
INNER JOIN book as b ON c.isbn = b.isbn 
INNER JOIN belong_to as be ON b.isbn = be.isbn 
INNER JOIN written_by as w ON w.isbn=b.isbn 
INNER JOIN author as a ON a.authID = w.authID
WHERE (c.isbn,c.copyNr) NOT IN (SELECT isbn, copyNr FROM borrows)
GROUP BY b.isbn
ORDER BY be.categoryName
```

The problem is that I get duplicate tuples on the result before grouping which leads to more items per group.

For instance for some books I get the attribute value of Number_of_copies_available double than expected.

If I don't `JOIN` with the relations "written_by" and "author" then the result is correct. However, I also want to appear the author names in the result. What's my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't worry about duplicates make sure your GROUP BY is correct first.. As that is generaly not how you should be using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) .. Your query can be valid only when MySQL can use [functionally dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Comment: As your query is most likely wrong i would suggest to read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and matching epexted results..

Comment: Learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  Your query won't run in any other dbms.

Comment: What's wrong with it? I wanted to group by every ISBN in order to see the number of copies for each one.

Comment: *"What's wrong with it?"* if you would read mine linked documentation links you would know what is wrong..

Comment: What if there are a few authors of one book? In that case join to written_by may duplicate rows.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I read that...Still a bit confused..Could you explain me where the mistake exactly is and how could I fix this?

Comment: You need to specify the aggregate logic for non grouped by columns. That's what's wrong with your group by as far as I can tell.

Comment: *"Still a bit confused..Could you explain me where the mistake exactly is and how could I fix this? "* see mine second comment about making a Minimal Reproducible example and mine posted "answer"

Comment: Don't just join everything and then see how to muddle through. If you join the tables on ISBN, you get all combinations of authors and categories for a book. With three authors and two categories, this makes already six result rows, each combining one of the authors with one of the categories. That makes hardly sense. So start with a result table. What shall it look like? What to show in the mentioned case? One author and one category arbitrarily picked? A string of all authors and another of all categories?

Comment: As to `GROUP BY`: With `GROUP BY b.isbn` you get one result row per ISBN. But then you select `be.categoryName`. Which of the book's categories? You forgot to tell the DBMS. The first in the alphabet? That would be `MIN(be.categoryName)`. You need aggregation functions to tell the DBMS what to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't join the tables directly when they are not perfectly related. A book's category is not really related to a book's author. With two authors and two categories, which author would you combine with which category? It makes no sense to combine them (and possibly end up with all combinations). So, aggregate first and then join the aggregates. Here is an example:

```
select
  b.isbn,
  b.title,
  b.pubName,
  aut.authors,
  cat.categories,
  cop.total - coalesce(bor.total, 0) as available
from book b
join
(
  select w.isbn, group_concat(a.alast) as authors
  from  written_by w
  join author a ON a.authID = w.authID
  group by w.isbn
) aut ON aut.isbn = b.isbn
join
(
  select isbn, group_concat(categoryname) as categories
  from  belong_to
  group by isbn
) cat ON cat.isbn = b.isbn
join
(
  select isbn, count(*) as total
  from  copies
  group by isbn
) cop ON cop.isbn = b.isbn
left join
(
  select isbn, count(*) as total
  from  borrows
  where date_of_return > current_date
  group by isbn
) bor ON bor.isbn = b.isbn
order by b.isbn;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!I get an error : `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.categories,
   cop.total - coalesce(bor.total, 0) as available
 from book b
 jo' at line 6`

Comment: Well, there may be errors in the query. I typed it from scratch without a database at hand. If you study the query and understand it, you will probably find the error quickly. You may start by reducing the query to authors first, then extend it to categories, etc. and see when the error appears. Hint: The error is in the select clause. It's not too hard to find :-)

Comment: I cannot fix it. Is it a problem that I am running the query on MySQL 5.7.26?

Comment: No, there is a comma missing after `aut.authors`.

Comment: Oh yeah! I fixed it now and it works..However, it doesn't return the desired resutls. To make it more clear the desired results are the the books that are given by the following query: `SELECT b.isbn, b.title, b.pubName, be.categoryName , COUNT(b.isbn) as Number_of_copies_available
FROM copies as c INNER JOIN book as b ON c.isbn = b.isbn INNER JOIN belong_to as be ON b.isbn = be.isbn
WHERE (c.isbn,c.copyNr) NOT IN (SELECT isbn, copyNr FROM borrows)
GROUP BY b.isbn
ORDER BY be.categoryName ` This gives me exactly what I want. I just want to add the author names as well. How do I do this?

Comment: What I want is to show the books that have one or more copies available and how many copies there are

Comment: I think the problem is in the statement: date_of_return > current_date ... I have as default value null if the member hasn't returned the book yet...Does this affect that?

Comment: @MJ13 the best to always follow this example and do aggregates like `COUNT(*)` in deliverd table a.k.a subqueries like Thorsten Kettner answer that way you can never get the surprise that a one-to-many or many-to-many relation join is multiplying the count results as it is a very common mistake to make.

Comment: @MJ13: Yes, of course it does. You may want `(date_of_return > current_date or date_of_return is null)`. And if you never set this date in advance, but only when the book is actually returned, it suffices to use `date_of_return is null` to find the not yet returned books.

Answer (score 1):

> Still a bit confused..Could you explain me where the mistake exactly
>   is and how could I fix this?

Not really meant as a answer, as this "comment" is way to large.

But a more SQL 92 valid rewrite would be more or less like below. 
But as you didn't provide example data and expected results iám really guessing what you need

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 book.isbn
 ...
FROM
 book
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(book.isbn) AS Number_of_copies_available
  FROM
   book
  INNER JOIN 
   copies
  ON
   book.isbn = copies.isbn

  ... # borrows table should also be needed here to be filterd? 
) AS book_copies__count
ON
...
...
...
```

Comment: I wrote the following query which gives me the desired result `SELECT b.isbn, b.title, b.pubName, be.categoryName , COUNT(b.isbn) as Number_of_copies_available
FROM copies as c INNER JOIN book as b ON c.isbn = b.isbn INNER JOIN belong_to as be ON b.isbn = be.isbn
WHERE (c.isbn,c.copyNr) NOT IN (SELECT isbn, copyNr FROM borrows WHERE borrows.date_of_return IS NULL)
GROUP BY b.isbn
ORDER BY be.categoryName` However I want to add columns with author's first and last name. How do I have to join now to achieve this?

Comment: That query still most likely still wrong @MJ13 it uses GROUP BY still invalid see mine first comment under your question.

Comment: But here I join only three relations that can be related uniquely if I am not mistaken. I get the desired result

Comment: @MJ13 whats wrong with the other answer you accepted? When accepting a answer your question is basically done on this website.

Comment: I just noticed that I don't get the correct resutls. And can't figure out what's wrong. What's the purpose of the statement date_of_return > current_date in the last subquery?

Comment: *"What's the purpose of the statement date_of_return > current_date in the last subquery"* You should be asking @ThorstenKettner as he has posted a answer with that filter..  But it means that the columns date should be greater then today's date

Comment: Yeah I will...He just didn't respond. What I don't get is why is this statement for? date of return is always Null or less or equal to the current date. Anyway thanks for help!